# Is NFS hard- or soft-mounted to Kubernetes Pods?

Tags: kubernetes

Is NFS hard- or soft-mounted when making a Pod in Kubernetes with an NFS-volume?

As I understand this might have an impact on how it handles a timeout?

Example yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nfs-web
spec:
  containers:
- name: web
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - name: web
      containerPort: 80
  volumeMounts:
      - name: nfs
        mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
  volumes:
    - name: nfs
      nfs:
        server: nfs-server.default.kube.local
        path: "/"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the NFS mounts inside of a POD will use the defaults provided by the implementation of NFS in the container OS. I can't be 100% certain (I'm not deeply familiar with the code), but in my experience the NFS mounts are mounted with the `hard` option, which is default in most implementations of NFS (see `man nfs` for more details on your OS; `soft` is often considered dangerous.)

The [NFSVolumeSource struct](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/c96c76b729da3f4990bcbfdfa7cb89e379436bf3/pkg/api/types.go#L515-L526) doesn't appear to have the ability to know about mount settings (except read-only) and I don't see any hard-coded options in the [NFS volume code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/c1eb1a1b2f334312f8b4f91877f1fced941dc786/pkg/volume/nfs/nfs.go).

You can check on your own PODs with something like this to gather the NFS options in use:

`$ kubectl exec  nfs-web-<XXXXX> -c web -- mount|grep nfs`

Answer (score 2):

its always "hard" mounted by default...however you can change it to soft by explicitly passing the additional annotation in PV definition.

```
volume.beta.kubernetes.io/mount-options: soft
```